# how to slice a pandas data frame more elegantly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice

i'm wondering if there is a better way to slice a data frame with different criteria for the same variable.

actually i'm looking at this example:
`df_european_union = df[(df['Country'] == 'Austria')|(df['Country'] == 'Belgium')|(df['Country'] == 'Bulgaria')...`

this works just fine but i don't think it's close to best practice.

already tried approaches like:
`df_european_union = df[(df['Country'] == ['Austria','Belgium', ... ]]`

or
`eu = ['Austria','Belgium','Bulgaria',...] df_european_union = df[(df['Country'] == eu]`

Comment: `df.Country.isin(eu)`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. You can do that using **query** or **isin** pandas method like

```py
df.loc[df.Contry.isin([liste_of_element]), :]
```

Or using **query** method like:

```py
df.query("Country == 'name_of_country' | Country == 'another_name_of_country'")
```

I think it'll solve your problem. Thanks